# How do I escape the # character in Cognos?

Tags: sql, cognos, cognos-8

I have created a pass-through Query Item in Cognos 8 Framework Manager that requires the # character as part of the query. Unfortunately this gets interpreted by Cognos as the opening of a macro.

How do I escape the # (number sign/sharp) character in a Query Item?

Answer (score 0):

There does't seem to be any "official" way in the documentation, but this seems to work.

```
#"#"#
```

`#'#'#` works too, unless it appears in a literal SQL string in your query, so it's safer to use `#"#"#`.

Answer (score -1):

A single backslash `\` should delimit it, I know it delimits square brackets `[]`.